# Citing an ISO standard with multiple parts, using Harvard style?

Tags: citations, citation-style, bibtex

I would like to cite an ISO standard that is split into multiple parts, I want to cite the whole standard but am unsure of how to do this in Harvard style.

`ISO 14230 Road vehicles – Diagnostic systems – Keyword Protocol 2000` has 4 different parts

- ISO 14230-1 Physical layer
- ISO 14230-2 Data link layer
- ISO 14230-3 Application layer
- ISO 14230-4 Requirements for emission-related systems

In my text I would like to cite the whole document something like ISO 14230 (year) but am unsure whether this would be correct, Which year would I put the year of the first part or the last part? (The different parts of the ISO have been published or updated on different years)

My bibtex currently looks like this:

```
@techreport{ISO14230,
type = {Standard},
key = {ISO 14230},
year = {1999},
title = {{Road vehicles - Diagnostic systems - Keyword Protocol 2000}},
publisher = {British Standards Institution},
institution = {International Organization for Standardization},
note = {Available from: \url{https://bsol.bsigroup.com/en/}}
}
```

Comment: To clarify, the different parts were published on different years? If so, it would help to edit that clarification into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After speaking to university librarians about this and although they could not find any official guidelines, they suggested that within the Bibliography I reference each part of the ISO individually:

```
@techreport{ISO14230part1,
type = {Standard},
key = {ISO 14230-1},
year = {2012},
title = {{Road vehicles. Diagnostic communication over K-Line (DoK-Line). Physical layer}},
publisher = {British Standards Institution},
institution = {International Organization for Standardization},
note = {Available from: \url{https://bsol.bsigroup.com/en/}}
}

@techreport{ISO14230part2,
type = {Standard},
key = {ISO 14230-2},
year = {2013},
title = {{Road vehicles. Diagnostic communication over K-Line (DoK-Line). Data link layer}},
publisher = {British Standards Institution},
institution = {International Organization for Standardization},
note = {Available from: \url{https://bsol.bsigroup.com/en/}}
}

@techreport{ISO14230part3,
type = {Standard},
key = {ISO 14230-3},
year = {1999},
title = {{Road vehicles. Diagnostic systems. Keyword Protocol 2000. Application layer}},
publisher = {British Standards Institution},
institution = {International Organization for Standardization},
note = {Available from: \url{https://bsol.bsigroup.com/en/}}
}

@techreport{ISO14230part4,
type = {Standard},
key = {ISO 14230-4},
year = {2000},
title = {{Road vehicles. Diagnostic systems. Keyword Protocol 2000. Requirements for emission related systems}},
publisher = {British Standards Institution},
institution = {International Organization for Standardization},
note = {Available from: \url{https://bsol.bsigroup.com/en/}}
}
```

and then within the text to reference using the years in brackets: `ISO 14230 (2013; 2012; 2000; 1999)`. Noting that even though the years do not correspond with the order of the different parts but when referencing works by the same author the most recent comes first.